# Checking if file two directories up and two directories down exists

Tags: java, file, exists

So consider this code:

```
public boolean exists(String path)
{
    return new File(path).exists();
}
```

Now let's say the jar executing this code is \home\program1\jars\checker.jar

Now let's suppose there is a text file \home\program2\texts\test.txt

How can I check if that text file exists using my checker.jar in the other directory without knowing the absolute path?

Would

```
exists("\\..\\..\\program2\\texts\\text.txt")
```

work?

Help would be really appreciated (:

Comment: Starting with a slash means an absolute path from the root, so "/.." by definition is not going to work since the root has no parent.

Comment: Also, any relative path you use will be relative to the working directory which is not necessarily the folder containing the jar. It depends on how you launch your program.

Comment: @Andrei Nicusan: Yes. It does not seem to work.

Comment: Please show how you invoke your program.

Comment: @schmop: I'm not sure what you mean. Is the working directory not the directory containing the .jar using the code?

Comment: @schmop: I'm currently running it from netbeans. System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath()); returns
C:\Users\Expert\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Showcases\checker
(yes I didn't use real directories in the example on the top of the page)

Comment: @JonasBartkowski Not necessarily. If you double click a runnable jar in windows, it is (AFAIK). If you use the _java_ command, it is the working directory of your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the current directory is indeed *\home\program1\jars*, then

```
exists("../../program2/texts/text.txt")
```

should work. Notice that java can use forward slashes on any platform.